# A problem with array and checking the values inside

Tags: javascript

Hello recently I was working with arrays in JavaScript and appear a little problem with a function.

**My problem** is in the function **checkRepeat**, in this function I try to know if I click a Card before or not, when I click the first Card work but with the other cards they don't work, I was thinking that my problem maybe it's for the loop because maybe it's taking only one element but I don't know.

This is my code:

```
const cardArray = [
    {name: 'fries'},
    {name: 'pizza'},
    {name: 'hotdog'},
    {name: 'cheeseburger'},
    {name: 'milkshake'},
    {name: 'ice-cream'}
]
const emptyCard = [
    {name: 'white'},
    {name: 'blank'}
]
// the format of the img
const format = '.png'
// I select the place where I gonna put the board
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
const cardsChosen = [];
const cardsChosenId = [];


const createBoard = () =>{
    for(let n = 0; n < cardArray.length*2; n++)
    {
        // I create the img
        let card = document.createElement('img');
        card.src = `images/${emptyCard[1].name}${format}`;
        card.id = `card-${n}`
        card.addEventListener('click',flipCard)
        grid.appendChild(card)
    }
}

function flipCard(){
    // I get the id, just the number
    let cardId = parseInt(this.getAttribute('id').slice(5,7));
    const v1 = checkRepeat(cardsChosenId,cardId);
    console.log("Value: ",v1)
    //console.log("Values in the array: ",cardsChosenId)
}

function checkRepeat(array,value){
    if(array.length === 0){// if the array is empty
        array.push(value);//push in the array the value
        return true;// and return true
    }
    else{// if isn't
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){// walk through the array
            if(array[i] === value){// check if the values of the array === value
                return false;
            }
            else{// if the value and the array values are different
                array.push(value);//push the value
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

createBoard();
```

Comment: *"they don't work"* doesn't provide us any meaningful debugging details. What happens, how is it different than expected, what troubleshooting have you done , are there errors etc?

Comment: Unless you need an array, I think an object or a Map would work better for your case.

Comment: Sorry let my explain better, when I click in the Card I save the number that I design before and in the function where I have the problem go through the whole arrangement and it will only return true or false, only if there is a value stored in the array.

Comment: one little doubt, It is possible that when it went through the array and when it found me a value equal to the one that I compare, it returns false, but after that it continues to go through the same array and add that value inside because it compared it with a totally different one?

Comment: You can store the whole id in data-id atrribute. For checking, if an array contains an element, use the includes method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp, better use a set https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the code, the problem was the logic.

Because when it traversed the array, it finds an equal value, but it continues traversing the array and the other values ​​do not resemble the compared value, so it adds the same values ​​to me later in the array.

I explain:

When I click on each of the cards, they save the id in an arrangement, and if I click again on a card that I had previously given it, it would compare with each element and when it found the same one, it would return false, but continued scrolling the whole arrangement and added more elements to the arrangement when I shouldn't have.

Example:

I click on the 1st element, [0] is saved, I click on the second [0,1] and I give the second element again and when comparing 0 with 1 I find that they are different and it remains like this [0,1,1] when it should return only [0,1]

I resolve with includes:

```
function checkRepeat(array,value){
   if(array.includes(value)){//return true if value it's in the array
        return false;
    }
    else{
        array.push(value);
        return true;
    }
}
```